# Alternate way of using the geocoder class for getting the lat and long by giving the place name or address

Tags: java, android, maps

i struck up with the FWD geocoder issue "service not found"in getting the lat and long of a place ,can u please help me the other way how can i get the lat and long of  a place with or without using the geocoder.so that i can mark a location on the map using lat and long.

Comment: are you trying to find latitude and longitude in a loop?I am meaning for more than one location.

Comment: i cant get even one location also with the geocoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the Android GeoCoder object, Google also provides a Geocoding Web Service, which offers a REST interface that can respond in JSON and XML formats. See http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html for more info.